# AWS transition to ipv6, does aws do ipv4 address embedding?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipv6

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html

There are lots of ipv6 roadblocks (cable/home internet, office network) that is ipv4 only, so we have a clustered application that runs dual stack ipv6 and ipv4.

We run a command against one of the clustered application nodes to report all the other nodes. Those come back in ipv6, but we need to interface to them via ipv4. So we'd like to be able to determine the ipv4 address from the reported ipv6 addresses.

One of the ipv4 --> ipv6 transition techniques is ipv6 addresses that have the ipv4 address embedded:
http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6IPv4AddressEmbedding-2.htm

I didn't see any mention of this in AWS info, anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: "_So we'd like to be able to determine the ipv4 address from the reported ipv6 addresses._" It doesn't work like that. IPv4-Mapped IPv6 addresses cannot be source or destination addresses and are not routable (see the _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_). IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate protocols, and addressing for one does not relate to addressing for the other.

Comment: We are running dual stacks. I'm asking for an ipv6 allocation strategy that has the ipv4 equivalent address of the instance in the ipv6 address. I'm not asking for a ipv4 address that will route through ipv6, just a way for AWS to allocate the ipv4 and ipv6 addresses on the dual stack that are convertible without a service lookup or if there is a standard service like DNS that exists for this.

Comment: That is not how it works. Would you ask for equivalent IPv4, IPX, IPv6 AppleTalk, etc. addresses? No, they are all completely separate protocols with completely separate addressing schemes.

Comment: - we have internal addresses for our ipv4 from the VPC

- ipv6 should have plenty of space to have the equivalent AWS ipv4 internal embedded in the least-significant part of the ipv6 address

It seems pretty sad that ipv6 didn't propose good paths for ipv4 --> ipv6 transition using the basic things I've listed or more useful alternatives. Hopefully AWS and other cloud providers figure this out.

Comment: You can only do it manually. There is no inherent correlation between IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.